# Asterisk instantly terminates WebRTC (JSSIP) call

Tags: linux, webrtc, asterisk, sip, jssip

I'm running Asterisk 11.2.2 with SRTP and STUN support under Calculate Linux (Gentoo-based distribution).

When I try to call from one WebRTC instance to another, using JSSIP, the call passes, but if i answer it on another instance, the call suddenly terminates. Using Asterisk debug mode, i can catch 488 error (Not acceptable here).

If I use one SIP phone (Ekiga) instance instead of WebRTC, then I can call JSSIP from it, and everything works fine. Nevertheless, I can't call Ekiga from JSSIP, and this makes me confused.

Can you advise me, what have I do to localize this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in my Asterisk: it had some WebRTC issues in 11.2.2 version. Upgrading to 11.4.0 makes everything works fine.

Comment: I also had the same experience in v11.2. It appears to be related to  SRTP crypto tags not being properly propagated.  Tested and working in 11.6 also.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue, for me it was codecs issue. I was allowing only G729 in sip.conf file and hence it was throwing 488 error. For now, I fixed it by setting allow=all (I would check later on which particular codec does it needs).